# How to compare nodes and not add duplicates in C?

Tags: c, struct, compare, nodes

I have three nodes as follows.

First node (sNodes) contains: a,b,c,d
Second node (rNodes) contains: c,d,e,f
Third node (nodes) contains: a,b,c,d

I want to add any nodes from second node that is not in the third node. I am having hard time how to do it in C as I am just a beginner. I tried using strcmp method in for loop but couldn't solve it that way. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
typedef struct {
char emails[(LENGTH*2)+1];
}Node;
Node nodes[GRAPH_SIZE + 1], sNodes[(GRAPH_SIZE + 1) / 2], rNodes[(GRAPH_SIZE + 1)/2];

void addNode(){
int j =0,k = 0, compare, total;
char item[] = {0};

for(j = 0; j <= GRAPH_SIZE/2; j++){
    total = 0;
    for(k = 0; k <= GRAPH_SIZE/2; k++){
        if(strcmp(rNodes[j].emails, nodes[k].emails) != 0){
            total = 1;
        }else {
            total = 0;
        }

    }
    if(total == 1){
        strcpy(nodes[i].emails, rNodes[j].emails);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you provided is not completed or buggy,
(like unused sNodes, item, compare...and I can't find where is i)
and what you want to do is also unclear for me.

But let me suppose you want to do compare, if not match, do some copy.
Then you should break the for strcmp loop when you find unmatch node,
so you can copy target node, not just set flag.